# Analysing constrained motion involving massless string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image: Here is the question.]

**My line of thought:**

> **Horizontal:** As A moves with 10m/s towards right, B also moves right with same speed. Therefore C also moves with 10m/s towards right. B slides along incline with 5m/s. It has horizontal component of 4m/s. Therefore, net horizontal velocity of block C is 10+4=14m/s.

> **Vertical:** As A moves with 10m/s right, the string also moves with 10m/s. Hence, string connected with C also moves 10m/s downwards. B moves along incline with speed 5m/s, it has   3m/s as vertical component. Therefore net vertical velocity of C is 10+3=13m/s.

My answer for horizontal component is right but for vertical component, it is wrong. Can anybody help me figure out what did I miss?
Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** Actual answer for vertical component is 26m/s.

Comment: That pulley also contribute to its vertical velocity

Comment: I wish to answer your question but its closed i dont know why op has clearly shown his efforts

Comment: It is still a “homework/check my work” type asking about a specific computation.

Comment: @Prateek Mourya I think I considered that too.

Comment: I used virtual work method and got 23 m/s